# How come a buttons background starts flashing after you click it?

Tags: vb.net, background

Currently when i click on a button on my vb.net form that has a color (or a picture) associated with it, it does the action of whatever it's suppose to do

But then,

it starts flashing ... ?

Is it possible to make it not flash after you click it?

edit: This is the XAML of the button

```
<Button Content="↑ Import" Height="57" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="485,87,0,0" Name="ButtonImport" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="126" Grid.Column="1" Background="Lime" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set **Focus()** on **something else** at the bottom of the event handler for the Button it will stop the button's background from flashing.

For Example:

```
Private Sub ButtonRefresh_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles ButtonRefresh.Click
    refresh()  


    ListViewOrderDetail.Focus()
End Sub
```